# Xcode 7 UI Testing - can't type text into search bar

Tags: swift, xcode7, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

The following `UI Test` code will successfully tap the `UISearchBar` element. The software keyboard appears and the search bar looks like it has focus. (ie. it animates as if someone tapped it)

```
let searchBar = XCUIApplication().otherElements["accessibility_label"]
searchBar.tap()
searchBar.typeText("search text")
```

However, typeText fails with:

> UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard
>   focus. Element:

**Note:** Hardware->Keyboard->Connect Hardware Keyboard is toggled off. This solved the same issue for text fields but the search bar is still failing.

Comment: Why are you using `otherElements`? Can you try with `searchBars`?

Comment: I don't see a searchBar element but I did try searchFields. Unfortunately no matches could be found. So I used the UI recorder and XCode identified the element with otherElements. Seems to be the only way I can access it. I'm guessing that's abnormal? Haha. Have you been able to access a UISearchBar with the searchFields command?

Comment: What happens when you try to find the element by different methods? Like `staticTexts()` or `elementBoundByIndex()`? Is this simulating iPad or iPhone?

Comment: Just hit this problem too.  I had to remove the accessibility from the UISearchBar and then I was able to use XCUIApplication().typeText() to type into (it already has focus when the search view controller appears).

Answer (score 14):

I found something:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.tables.searchFields["Search"].tap()
app.searchFields["Search"].typeText("something")
```

It looks strange, but it works for me.

Comment: but what if i want to identify searchField using accessible identifier? Because it causing issue while we providing multi-language support.

Comment: The above has been used using the accessible identifier only.. The `Search` is the accessible identifier for searchField.

Answer (score 5):

it worked for me to set

```
searchBar.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitSearchField
```

in the view controller and then access it in the UI test by

```
let searchfield = app.searchFields.element(boundBy: 0) 
searchfield.typeText("foobar")
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the following workaround successfully:

```
let firstCell = app.cells.elementBoundByIndex(0)
let start = firstCell.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0, 0))
let finish = firstCell.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0, 3))
start.pressForDuration(0, thenDragToCoordinate: finish)

app.searchFields.element.tap()
app.searchFields.element.typeText("search text")
```

This effectively scrolls the search bar into view and taps it to focus, after that `typeText()` can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following (Swift 4, Xcode 9.4.1):

```
app.searchFields["Placeholder"].clearAndEnterText("String to search")
app.buttons["Search"].tap()
```

... where "Placeholder" is the string that appears in the textfield before typing the text.

Note: *clearAndEnterText* is a function created in a XCUIElement extension:

```
    func clearAndEnterText(_ text: String)
    {
        guard let stringValue = self.value as? String else {
            XCTFail("Tried to clear and enter text into a non string value")
            return
        }

        self.tap()

        let deleteString = String(repeating: XCUIKeyboardKey.delete.rawValue, count: stringValue.count)

        self.typeText(deleteString)
        self.typeText(text)
    }
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Just put a wait for few seconds and it will work!

```
let searchBar = XCUIApplication().otherElements["accessibility_label"]
searchBar.tap()
sleep(5)
searchBar.typeText("search text")
```